# XSL: Spurious output using template match

Tags: xml, xslt, transform

I have an XSL stylesheet that I use to create xHTML fragments.  The XML contains lots of information and I only want to transform one particular section, I match this like so (note this is my top level/first match):

```
<xsl:template match="root/SystemInfo/Errors">
```

This works great, however, before my intended output I see `1001` being written out.  Upon further inspection this is the data of various tags that preceed my matched xpath `"root/SystemInfo/Errors"`.  What can I do to prevent this from happening?

Example xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<root>
    <Settings>
        <Enabled>1</Enabled>
        <Mode1>0</Mode1>
        <Mode2>0</Mode2>
        <Limit>1</Limit>
    </Settings>
    <SystemInfo>
        <Errors>
            <NOCONNECTION>1</NOCONNECTION>
        </Errors>
    </SystemInfo>
</root>
```

XML Playground [setup here](http://www.xmlplayground.com/7u8bns) to show the effect.

Comment: If it's not massive, would be useful to see the whole XSLT

Comment: It's HUGE! Everything matches subsections of the original match (`"root/SystemInfo/Errors"`)

Comment: It seems that, because I'm not explicitly dealing with the rest of the XML its reverting to a "default" mode whereby it just outputs the data in those tags... Do I need a match="*" to catch these and just do nothing inside?

Comment: Fair enough @Chris, understood... however, without something to work with, it's going to be tricky... hopefully somebody will have an idea without needing to see it. Good luck

Comment: is it worth setting up an http://xmlplayground.com?

Comment: @freefaller Nice site!!!

Comment: In case it's not obvious to you (because it wasn't to me and took several minutes of head-scratching) you need to "involve" the sections other than the XML for the transformations to do anything

Comment: @freefaller Thanks mate, I updated the question and yes it took me a few minutes to figure that out as well!

Comment: Erm, I think it works differently from jsfiddle... I saved a change (thinking it would create a new version) but I think it's updated your original! Can you check your link to see if you're seeing the new `template` section I've added?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add

```
<xsl:template match="text()"/>
```

to override the default templates outputting text nodes or make sure you process only the stuff you are interested in with

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="root/SystemInfo/Errors"/>
</xsl:template>
```